# npgsql not importing to unity 2022.3.4f1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, npgsql

I have been trying to get the npgsql.dll package to import into unity and cannot get it to save my life. I downloaded npgsql.dll v7.0.4 and have drug and dropped it into the assets/plugins folder. However, once the project rebuilds, I get this error:

```html
Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/Npgsql.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'System.Threading.Channels'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'System.Text.Json'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
```

I have read a couple things online. I have read that the issue could potentially be with the .net version. To test this, I tried importing the net2.0, net2.1, and the net5.0 versions, all of which give me the same error. I have also read that it may have something to do with references, but I am not really sure what that means (I am new to unity and C#). I would assume the issue has to do with some version incompatibility somewhere, but I am not sure where or how to troubleshoot the issue. I have also tried npgsql v6.0.7 and v5.0.7, both of which gave me similar assembly issues. Anyone know what is going on here?